# Nodejs + ReactJS socket.io off/removeListener not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to implement socket.io on my react/nodejs app. I can successfully subscribe for an event and push the data to the front end. But I couldn't un-subscribe from an event when it is no longer needed.

**Version**
socket.io - 2.0.4
socket.io-client - 2.0.4

Below is the sample code

Frontend

```
subscribeForTimer() {
    socket.on('timer', timestamp => {
        console.log(timestamp)
    });
    socket.emit('subscribeToTimer', 1000);
}

UnubscribeFromTimer() {
    socket.removeListener ( 'timer', (data) => {
        console.log ( 'stopped' )
    } );
}
```

Backend

```
const socketServer = http.createServer ();
// create a server instance with the port and host
socketServer.listen ( port, host );

// Make the sockets listen on the created server instance
const sio = io.listen ( socketServer );
sio.sockets.on ( socketEvents.CONNECTION, ( socket ) => {
    subscribeToTimer ( socket );
    UnubscribeFromTimer ( socket );
    terminateConnection ( socket );
} );
function subscribeToTimer ( socket ) {
    socket.on ( 'subscribeToTimer', ( interval ) => {
        setInterval ( () => {
            socket.emit ( 'timer', new Date () );
        }, interval );
    } );
}
```

I have tried using off/removeListener/removeAllListeners but nothing works. It doesn't throw any errors either. Any help is much appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the same instance of the subscribed function to unsubscribe:

On frontend:

```js
const subscribeFn = timestamp => {
  console.log(timestamp)
}

subscribeForTimer() {
  socket.on('timer', subscribeFn);
  socket.emit('subscribeToTimer', 1000);
}

UnubscribeFromTimer() {
  socket.removeListener('timer', subscribeFn);
}
```

on Backend

```js
const socketServer = http.createServer ();
// create a server instance with the port and host
socketServer.listen ( port, host );

// Make the sockets listen on the created server instance
const sio = io.listen ( socketServer );
let intervalId;
sio.sockets.on ( socketEvents.CONNECTION, ( socket ) => {
    subscribeToTimer ( socket );
    intervalId && clearInterval(intervalId)
    UnubscribeFromTimer ( socket );
    terminateConnection ( socket );
} );
function subscribeToTimer ( socket ) {
    socket.on ( 'subscribeToTimer', ( interval ) => {
        intervalId = setInterval ( () => {
            socket.emit ( 'timer', new Date () );
        }, interval );
    } );
}
```

Comment: thanks! In case if I want to stop emitting for that instance from the server is it the same way to do?

Comment: @confusedcoder not exactly, you need to handle the setInterval separately, check my updated answer